# preg match to get text after @ symbol and before next space using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I need help to find out the strings from a text which starts with `@` and till the next immediate space by `preg_match` in php

> Ex : I want to get @string from this line as separate.
>   In this example, I need to extract "@string" alone from this line.

Could any body help me to find out the solutions for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a Twitter username or something else?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If you provide code you've written already, people will be better able to help you.

Comment: No, it is not twitter username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP and Python are not the same in regard to searches. If you've already used a function like `strip_tags` on your capture, then something like this might work better than the Python example provided in one of the other answers since we can also use [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
I want to get @string from this line as separate.
In this example, I need to extract "@string" alone from this line.

@maybe the username is at the front.

Or it could be at the end @whynot, right!

dog@cat.com would be an e-mail address and should not match.        

EOT;

echo $string."<br>";

preg_match_all('~(?<=[\s])@[^\s.,!?]+~',$string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Output results**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @string
            [1] => @maybe
            [2] => @whynot
        )

)
```

### Update

If you're pulling straight from the HTML stream itself, looking at the Twitter HTML it's formatted like this however:

```
<s>@</s><b>UserName</b>
```

So to match a username from the html stream you would match with the following:

```
<?php

$string = <<<EOT
<s>@</s><b>Nancy</b> what are you on about?

I want to get <s>@</s><b>string</b> from this line as separate. In this example, I need to extract "@string" alone from this line.

<s>@</s><b>maybe</b> the username is at the front.

Or it could be at the end <s>@</s><b>WhyNot</b>, right!

dog@cat.com would be an e-mail address and should not match.        

EOT;

$matchpattern = '~(<s>(@)</s><b\>([^<]+)</b>)~';
preg_match_all($matchpattern,$string,$matches);


$users = array();
foreach ($matches[0] as $username){
    $cleanUsername = strip_tags($username);
    $users[]=$cleanUsername;
}

print_r($users);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => @Nancy
    [1] => @string
    [2] => @maybe
    [3] => @WhyNot
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do simply:

```
preg_match('/@\S+/', $string, $matches);
```

The result is in `$matches[0]`